# Create component as child of element without overriding elements other children?

Tags: angular

I am dynamically generating components and attaching them to an element upon creation as children. However, each time I do this everything within that element is deleted.

Ex:

```js
public fn(event) {
    // Create component factory
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(NodeComponent);
    // Create component, attach to target
    const ref = factory.create(this.injector, [], event.target);
    // Register for change detection
    this.app.attachView(ref.hostView);
  }
```

Before update:

```html
<div class="parent">
  Network: 
  <app-node>child1</app-node>
</div>
```

After update:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>child2</div>
</div>
```

Note that "Network:" and app-node are both missing after the update. Furthermore, the generated NodeComponent doesn't have its app-node tag, but rather just its HTML content.

Any advice for how to stop this behaviour?
I am using Angular Version 7.39.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the renderer, but am still curious if its possible to do this with factory.create().

Solution:

```js
public fn(event) {
    // Create component factory
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(NodeComponent);
    // Create component
    const ref = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory)
    // Attach to target
    this.renderer.appendChild(
      event.target,
      ref.location.nativeElement
    );
}
```